# didn't get didDiscover peripheral ibeacon in background

Tags: ios, swift, bluetooth-lowenergy, ibeacon

When I specified service like this :

`centralManager.scanForPeripherals(withServices: [BEAN_SERVICE_UUID], options: [CBCentralManagerScanOptionAllowDuplicatesKey : true])`

I'm sure that I entered right `BEAN_SERVICE_UUID`. That's proved when I do that function in foreground, I can get didDiscover peripheral callback.

`func centralManager(_ central: CBCentralManager, didDiscover peripheral: CBPeripheral, advertisementData: [String : Any], rssi RSSI: NSNumber) {
        print(advertisementData)
}`

this is my general setting capabilities and my `info.plist`

[image]

[image]

So, what I must do to make ScanForPeripheral / didDiscover peripheral work ?

*edited
After testing many times, i got that my app can do background scanning peripherals, but just at initial launch (only once) after app installed, after that, ScanForPeripheral / didDiscover peripheral not working in background.

Comment: You can try centralManager.scanForPeripherals(withServices: nil) for scanning of all devices without specified UUID. CBCentralManagerScanOptionAllowDuplicatesKey key is ignored in background, so you can skip it for testing too. Also, maybe you has some errors in console?

Comment: In some search, i got that if we want scanning in background and foreground, we must specify the UUID. I've no error log, but the peripheral not discovered. After testing many times, i got that my app can do background scanning peripherals, but just at initial launch (only once) after app installed

Comment: Did you not forget cancel peripheral connection after you done everything you need after first lunch?

Comment: i didn't forget. but nothing happened with my background scanning

Comment: Did func centralManagerDidUpdateState(_ central: CBCentralManager) is called? Could you provide what are you doing in this method?

Comment: yes, it's called. I've print some text when didUpdateState being called.

Comment: Can you please show your definition of the callback methods?

Comment: i've update my question.

Answer (score 1):

When you are discovering Bluetooth peripherals in background `CBCentralManagerScanOptionAllowDuplicatesKey` is automatically ignored and set to false. With that being said you will receive only one advertisement packet in the background and you have to do some action with it. If you will not do that, this peripheral will never invoke `didDiscover` method again.

For iBeacons you should use CoreLocation framework.

Comment: so, I must set CBCentralManagerScanOptionAllowDuplicatesKey true or false?  what do you mean about receive only one advertisement packet in background? can you explain it?

Comment: In background the allow duplicates flag will be ignored. This means that you will now only get didDiscoverPeripheral callbacks for new devices. If all devices were seen whilst in the foreground you will get no callbacks at all.

Comment: if I'm using CoreLocation framework, can I discover beacon, connect, write and read?

Comment: You can start scanning for peripheral when CoreLocation beacon methods tell you that you are close